# What is the package for paginator on Liferay 7.4?

Tags: liferay, paginator

i need to customize the paginator on liferay 7.4, i need to create a fragment on eclipse for this and i dont know what is the package that i need to use. I need to overrrite start.jsp and
showing_x_results.jspf specifictly, i have the logic and the solution but i dont have any idea about the package or Host OSGI Bundle, someone could to help me, please.

[image]

Comment: If you already know that you "need" to override start.jsp, you'd typically know _which_ start.jsp you need to override - as there are potentially many. That would be the answer to the question you ask. Each jsp is contained in a certain bundle, and if you already changed it, you have retrieved it from somewhere. That's the bundle. Most likely there's a less invasive way to modify behavior, without JSP overrides. That'd be easier to maintain, but you don't tell us about your [underlying problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364505), so we can't recommend a proper solution.

Comment: Please also [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)